# Pyrus problems on Ubuntu 12 installing ZF2

Tags: php, ubuntu, pear, zend-framework2, pyrus

I tried to install zend framework 2 on Ubuntu 12.04.1 64 bit but have run into difficulties.

# sudo pyrus install  zf2/Zend_Framework-beta#Standard

failed mid transaction with no other previous errors that I can recall other than warnings about timezone not being set. ( Unfortuantely my terminal history has lost the original output)

Pyrus\Installer\Exception: Installation failed
  Pyrus\AtomicFileTransaction\MultiException: ERROR: commit failed
    Pyrus\IOException: CRITICAL - unable to complete transaction, rename of actual to backup path failed
      Pyrus\AtomicFileTransaction\RuntimeException: Cannot rollback - not in a transaction

Now when I try to rerun 
 
# sudo pyrus install -f zf2/Zend_Framework-beta#Standard 
it fails with 
Pyrus\Registry\Exception: Cannot retrieve package file object for package packages.zendframework.com/zend_framework, it is not installed

Uninstall just tells me that it's not installed.

I restored /usr/share/.old-php to /usr/share/php however I still get the same error.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can just try to download and unzip *Zend Framework 2 archive* into your project's library folder.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's a problem with the metapackage according the Matthew. I'm having the same problem.
[Error Installing full framework with Pyrus](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Install-full-framework-with-Pyrus-td4657786.html)

So if I installed pyrus here: "/usr/share/pear/pyrus" , then should I create a directory "/usr/share/pear/pyrus/zf2" and download and unzip the full Zend Framework in zf2 and it should work?

thanks

Comment: I gave up on pyrus and went with composer

Comment: Cool. I also just went with composer. They should really add a message about it in the pyrus section or fix it.